# Why isn't my input value updating with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my component. It will get called when I update certain things, thereby replacing a bunch of things in the UI. Everything is updating EXCEPT the value of the input as seen by the user.

```
let input = {
  id: 'discount-' + geo + '-' + segment,
  value: percentage,
  disabled: applyToAll,
  placeholder: '0.00'
};

cells.push(
  <td key={'cell-' + geo + '-' + segment} className="discount-segment cfix">
    <Text {...input} />
  </td>
);
```

This is what `<Text>` returns, with things removed for clarity

```
return (
  <div className={containerClasses.join(' ')} id={'field-container-' + id}>
    {label}
    <input
      autoComplete="off"
      type="text"
      id={id}
      ref="input"
      {...extraProps}
      name={id}
      className={classes.join(' ')}
      defaultValue={this.props.value}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      />
  </div>
);
```

Everything renders fine. Let's say the `percentage` value is `5` on start, it will show `5` in the field. I then do something else that updates `percentage` to 50. (A console log will show the right number on re-render). However the value is only showing `5` in the UI still. I am using `defaultValue` on the input field, but I figure that should be changing as the whole thing re-renders from parent.

**Edit**
Updated `<Text>` to set `value` instead of `defaultValue`. However then I need to use `state` to update the value when user types. Then when I re-render, I'm sending in new props with proper value, but of course props isn't updated. Catch-22 for me.

Comment: Are you sure the whole thing re-renders? What happens when you try to use value instead of defaultValue? (Plus, what's this.props.onChange doing?)

Comment: @TAGraves Right now I am not passing in onChange.. so nothing there. The lines above that show me using `<Text>` are inside `render` of a component. The render method has `{cells}` inside and that is getting called every time I expect it to be.

Comment: That doesn't mean that your input is being unmounted and then a new input is being rendered, though. `defaultValue` can't be updated after an initial render.

Comment: @TAGraces interesting, I'll have to give it a shot shortly. I remember ( a while back ) when I was using just value, it would go into read-only mode for certain inputs.

Comment: Yes, using value will make it a controlled input, so you'll have to update the value of the input in your onChange handler.

Comment: @TAGraves ah yeah that is where I lost my mind a while back. If I want onChange to update its value, how do I also pass in custom onChange? Know of a good article on that? like let's say UI needs to update on value so i want to look onChange of that?

Comment: Are you asking how to update the rest of the UI in the onChange handler? In order to do that, you'll have to pass (as a prop) a function in from the root of the UI that gets called in the handler. Why don't you wire up a JSFiddle with where you're getting stuck when you have a chance, and I'll see if I can give some recommendations.

Comment: @TAGraves made a gist https://gist.github.com/DaveStein/48f906e16f81e24bd90f17d2f706af52 does that seem about right?

Comment: Yep -  let's continue the discussion in the gist comments.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to perform a couple of steps:

1. Your input needs to *only* use the `value` and `onChange` props, do not use `defaultValue`
2. Initialize your state using your props to set your default value
3. Update your state when your props change

So, for example:

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    defaultInputValue: React.PropTypes.string
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      inputValue: this.props.defaultInputValue
    };
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.defaultInputValue !== this.props.inputValue) {
      //Forcibly overwrite input value to new default if the default ever changes
      this.setState({inputValue: nextProps.defaultInputValue});
    }
  },

  render() {
    return <input type="text"
                  value={this.state.inputValue}
                  onChange={e => this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})} />;
  }
});
```

In general initializing state off of props is a no-no. I would probably cringe a little bit if I saw this come across in a code review as there is probably some behavior that can be simplified.

You can also do:

```
<input value={this.state.inputValue || this.props.defaultInputValue} />
```

Such that the value of the input reverts to the prop value if you ever clear out the input. In this case you wouldn't have to forcibly overwrite the state with the new props.

Comment: Ahhh `componentWillReceiveProps` is a method I had glanced earlier and it didn't click. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can do it as this.We Must have to use onChnage() Event.

```
<input placeholder="as_you_want"
       value={this.state.as_your_state}
       onChange={e => {
           this.setState({ as_your_state: e.target.value });
           this.value = this.state.as_your_state;
       }}
/>
```

Hope This Works.

Comment: This is also the solution if you are wanting to use multiple select input boxes that are dependant on each other. Thanks @Usama

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is [deprecated now](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), and even its successor `getDerivedStateFromProps` is [recommended against](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). To square the circle of "I need to manage the state of a text input (state), but I also need it to update its initial value when I re-render (props)", the React blog recommended [using a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions) in the props. When the key changes, the component remounts and props can initialize state anew.

To aggressively force the component to refresh whenever anything about the input changes, I would use

```
    <Text {...input} key={JSON.stringify(input)}/>
```

Then you can use `value={this.state.value}` like a normal controlled form, but you can set `this.state.value = props.value` and it will change every time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just wanted to have the change handler not directly attached to the input but to the element wrapping it. It wasn't working because the input was using `value` instead of `checked` for the attribute...

#### Issue

```
<div onClick={() => setCheckboxVal(!checkboxVal)}>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="a-checkbox"
    value={checkboxVal}
  />
  <label htmlFor="a-checkbox"> Click Me</label>
</div>
```

#### Solution

```
<div onClick={() => setCheckboxVal(!checkboxVal)}>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="a-checkbox"
    checked={checkboxVal}
    readOnly
  />
  <label htmlFor="a-checkbox"> Click Me</label>
</div>
```