# Input output does not update straight away it is delayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have created two inputs and i update the state using `setState`.  When i type in the input and then `console.log` it doesn't log it straight away.

For example if i type "a n" into the input it will console log the "a" on the second key stroke...

I know that `this.setState` doesn't update straight away and batch updates the state, but when i have done this in the past it has worked. [Why isn't my input value updating with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683725/why-isnt-my-input-value-updating-with-react)

How can i get my inputs to update straight away? I want this to happen as i need to use the input by the user as a search keyword and pass each input value to a function.

code:

```
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movieTitleSearch: "",
      searchByYear: "",
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { movieTitleSearch } = this.state;
    const { searchByYear } = this.state;
    this.setState({    
          ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value, 
      },
      () => {
           if (movieTitleSearch || searchByYear > 1) {
           this.props.movieSearch(movieTitleSearch, searchByYear); 
       }
          console.log(movieTitleSearch) // does not update straight away in the console.
          console.log(searchByYear) // does not update straight away in the console.
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>search film title</label>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          type="text"
          name="movieTitleSearch"
          placeholder="search by film"
          value={this.state.movieTitleSearch}
        />
        <label>search by year</label>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          type="text"
          name="searchByYear"
          placeholder="search by year"
          value={this.state.searchByYear}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATED ONCHANGE FUNCTION

```
  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { movieTitleSearch } = this.state;
    const { searchByYear } = this.state;
    this.setState(
      {
       ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value, 
      },
    );
    this.props.movieSearch(this.state.movieTitleSearch, this.state.searchByYear) 
      console.log(this.state.movieTitleSearch) // why when i type in the inputs does this not log to the console straight away?
      console.log(this.state.searchByYear)
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the previous state when you use const `movieTitleSearch`.
You have to use it like `this.state.movieTitleSearch`, then you will get the updated state value.

```
handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { movieTitleSearch } = this.state;
    const { searchByYear } = this.state;
    this.setState({    
          ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value, 
      },
      () => {
           if (movieTitleSearch || searchByYear > 1) {
           this.props.movieSearch(this.state.movieTitleSearch, this.state.searchByYear); 
       }
          console.log(this.state.movieTitleSearch)
          console.log(this.state.searchByYear)
      }
    );
  };
```

Also, I would suggest calling the `movieSearch` outside of the `setState` callback, because you already have its value with you inside `event.target.value`

Comment: Thank for your comment i understand now that i was accessing the previous state, makes sense. However where do you think i should call the `movieSearch` then if not inside of the `setState` callback, can you give me an example please? @Rinkesh

Comment: After `this.setState({...});` call.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that :)

Comment: I'm still having the same problem... when i `console.log` it's not console logging what the user types in the input box straight away... i have updated the original question so you can see my updated `handleOnChange`

Comment: You are accessing `this.state` outside the callback. setState is an async function that won't be updated immediately.  There you have to use `event.target.value` as I mentioned in my answer.